# Classe em PHP para gerar código de barras no padrão code39 com ajuste de altura e largura

Tags: php, código-de-barras

Estou tendo dificuldades em gerar códigos de barras em PHP, no padrão `code39`, contendo 10 dígitos (apenas números), para impressão da página web contendo o código de barras **em impressoras térmicas**.

Já testei diversas classes, porém apresentam erro na leitura óptica.

Alguém poderia indicar uma boa classe em PHP para gerar código de barras no padrão `code39` e que permita ajustar altura e largura do código de barras?

Preferencialmente, algo que possa ser utilizado da seguinte forma:

```
<img src="/barcode.php?code=' . $cod_barras . '&largura=180&altura=80" />
```

Importante: preciso que ela funcione sem qualquer dependência além do PHP e da biblioteca `GD`.

Agradeço antecipadamente qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Eu costumo utilizar uma, mas ela é para Laravel 4 e 5. Chama-se Milon\Barcode.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, mas preciso que ela funcione sem qualquer dependência além da biblioteca GD.

Comment: Pode onde instalar? Eu uso o packagist. Lá você encontra qualquer coisa para php

Comment: Amigão, olha essa https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator

Comment: Wallace Maxters: a php-barcode-generator ficou com largura maior do que a bobina da impressora térmica... então  quando redimensiona para menor largura fica com má qualidade.

Comment: Não tem como configurar a resolução pela lib?

Comment: Baixei a resolução para 1px. Na impressora a jato de tinta fica bom, mas na térmica (Elgin i9) as linhas saem um pouco "pontilhadas". Tentando várias vezes o leitor até consegue ler, mas não é o ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após experimentar diversas classes, encontrei uma que atendeu bem com impressão de códigos de barras, com 10 dígitos, no padrão code39, em impressoras térmicas, sem dar problemas de leitura ou algo parecido.

[Barcode Generator: Web interface to generate barcode images](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2176-PHP-Web-interface-to-generate-barcode-images.html)

Apesar de ser uma classe cuja última atualização foi em 08/09/2005, funcionou muito bem para mim.

Espero que ajude se alguém passar pela mesma situação que eu passei.